# SQL Query works in management studio but not in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssms

I have a problem doing a query with my software...

I have a function which builds my query, and then execute it to fill a gridview. But it keep throwing me an exception : "The multi-part identifier ""  could not be bound" with several columns.

When I try the query in SQL Management Studio, it just works fine. I really don't understand. Here's the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [NonConformite].[Numero],
CAST ([NonConformite].[Numero] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ1, 
CAST ([NonConformiteDonneesComplementaires177_4].[Texte2] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ2, 
CAST (NonConformite.dbo.[NonConformiteStatut].[Libelle] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ3, 
CAST ([NonConformite].[Description] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ4 FROM [NonConformite].[dbo].[NonConformite]  
LEFT JOIN NonConformite.dbo.[NonConformiteDonneesComplementaires] as NonConformiteDonneesComplementaires177_4 
ON [NonConformite].[Numero] = [NonConformiteDonneesComplementaires177_4].[Numero] 
LEFT JOIN NonConformite.dbo.[NonConformiteStatut] 
ON [NonConformite].[CpteurStatut] = NonConformite.dbo.[NonConformiteStatut].[Cpteur]
```

I work on Windows 7 Pro, with Visual Studio 2008, SQL Server 2008 and in ASP.NET C#.

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: That is very hard to read... you know you can use aliases to help make the query sane, yes?

Comment: Can you try to create a procedure with this query, and try to execute procedure from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by breaking the query into aliases - see if that helps things; and unless you are *intentionally* doing cross-db work (usually a bad idea), drop the db identifier and just use the current db:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nc.[Numero],
CAST (nc.[Numero] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ1, 
CAST (dc.[Texte2] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ2, 
CAST (st.[Libelle] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ3, 
CAST (nc.[Description] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ4
FROM dbo.[NonConformite] nc
LEFT JOIN dbo.[NonConformiteDonneesComplementaires] dc
ON nc.[Numero] = dc.[Numero] 
LEFT JOIN dbo.[NonConformiteStatut] st
ON nc.[CpteurStatut] = st.[Cpteur]
```

Comment: Adding alias makes the Program more understandable, the approach u have done have some ambiquities which is throwing the Exception. According to @Marc Gravell, the Cross-db work will be a main reason for this type of Problems

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to do cross-db work, because I am converting a standard application into a web application. And I have to use the same DB.

Comment: @Mark : The former developper made 8 DB for one application, and some of them shares table name.

I tried your query, and it works fine in Visual Studio now (I added the DB name).

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following, and remove the comments from the bottom upwards till you can identify where the problem is.

```
SELECT *
--DISTINCT [NonConformite].[Numero],
--CAST ([NonConformite].[Numero] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ1, 
--CAST ([NonConformiteDonneesComplementaires177_4].[Texte2] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ2, 
--CAST (NonConformite.dbo.[NonConformiteStatut].[Libelle] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ3, 
--CAST ([NonConformite].[Description] AS varchar (255)) AS Champ4
FROM [NonConformite].[dbo].[NonConformite]  
-- LEFT JOIN NonConformite.dbo.[NonConformiteDonneesComplementaires] as NonConformiteDonneesComplementaires177_4 
    ON [NonConformite].[Numero] = [NonConformiteDonneesComplementaires177_4].[Numero] 
-- LEFT JOIN NonConformite.dbo.[NonConformiteStatut] 
    ON [NonConformite].[CpteurStatut] = NonConformite.dbo.[NonConformiteStatut].[Cpteur]
```